Where is zoom level in VS 2022
I can't find where to see the current zoom level in my fresh installation of VS2022, I've searched around in the options and tried resetting stuff but still can't find it. It has always been to the the left in the status bar.


Turn on the horizontal scroll bar.
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Scroll Bars -> Show horizontal scroll bar


Aha, didn't notice that the horizontal scroll bar was missing. Both settings were already on, but unchecking->checking->clicking OK made the horizontal scroll and zoom come back. Some hick-up it seems. Thanks for the help!
